# Javascript setInterval randomly stops

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, setinterval

I'm using setInterval to call a function that animates a fractal on a HTML5 canvas.  There is also a slider to allow the user to change the quality of the fractal. Everything works fine until I start changing the slider.  When I change it, the fractal animation becomes choppy, and eventually the "drawFractal" function stops being called.
Here is the slider HTML:

```
<input type="range" id="qualitySlider" min="1" max="10"></input>
```

Here is the javascript (it just generates a fractal):

```
var count = 0.5;

var slider = document.getElementById("qualitySlider");
var g = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas").getContext("2d");

function drawFractal() {
    var cellSize = Math.ceil(slider.value);
    //canvas is 700 by 400
    g.fillStyle = "black";
    g.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 400);

    //Eveything from here to the end of this function generates the fractal
    var imagC = Math.cos(count)*0.8;
    var realC = Math.sin(count)*0.5;
    for (x = 0; x < 700; x+=cellSize) {
        for (y = 0; y < 400; y+=cellSize) {
            var yCoord = (x / 700.0 - 0.5)*3;
            var xCoord = (y / 400.0 - 0.5)*3;
            var real = xCoord;
            var imag = yCoord;

            var broken = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                var temp = real*real - imag*imag + realC;
                imag = 2*imag*real + imagC;
                real = temp;
                if (real*real + imag*imag >= 4) {
                    broken = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!broken) {
                g.fillRect(x, y, cellSize, cellSize);
            }
        }
    }
    count = count + 0.04;
}

setInterval(drawFractal, 60);
```

I just need the "drawFractal" function to be called reliably every 60 milliseconds.

Comment: use `requestAnimationFrame`. safari is notorious for skipping timer events.

Comment: Are you sure you can execute this function in less than 60ms?  Your inner most `for` loop is going to be executed as many as 2.2 million times (700 * 400 * 8) each time it is called.  I wonder if the browser is just realizing the futility of calling this every 60ms when it doesn't complete in less than that.

Comment: A recursive setTimeout may be a better approach if the method could take longer than the set interval to compute, better still request animation frame as suggested.

Comment: @IGNIS I'm new to javascript, but I don't think I have a handler for the slider.  I do have setInterval somewhere else in my code, but it is not being called in this case.

Comment: @jfriend00 My computer and browser can handle the code just fine. The code just completely stops running (sometimes) when I change the slider's value.

Comment: The requestAnimationFrame fixed the problem

Comment: @DanielWilliams - Can you post an answer with your requestAnimationFrame fix? There is nothing wrong with answering your own question.

Comment: @DanielWilliams - I wouldn't be so sure it can handle it just fine when the slider value gets to be `1` or less than `1`.  That's when your `for` loops have an enormous number of iterations to do.  `requestAnimationFrame()` can make it more self adapting rather than on a fixed interval and that could be why it fixes your problem.

Comment: @DanielWilliams In the vein of what jfriend00 is saying, the way JavaScript works is that there is a stack of currently executing functions, and also a queue for "asynchronous" functions, like `setInterval`. If the stack never clears (like jfriend00 is suggesting because your function takes too long too execute), requestInterval will be never be called again because **queued functions only get called once the stack is empty**. You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

Answer (score 0):

This is my improved code. I just used requestAnimationFrame to recursively call the "drawFractal" function.  I also restricted the animation to 24 frames/sec with the setTimeout function.

```
var count = 0.5;

var qualitySlider = document.getElementById("qualitySlider");
var g = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas").getContext("2d");

function drawFractal() {
    var cellSize = Math.ceil(qualitySlider.value);
    //canvas is 700 by 400
    g.fillStyle = "black";
    g.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 400);
    var imagC = Math.cos(count)*0.8;
    var realC = Math.sin(count)*0.5;
    for (x = 0; x < 700; x+=cellSize) {
        for (y = 0; y < 400; y+=cellSize) {
            var yCoord = (x / 700.0 - 0.5)*3;
            var xCoord = (y / 400.0 - 0.5)*3;
            var real = xCoord;
            var imag = yCoord;

            var broken = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                var temp = real*real - imag*imag + realC;
                imag = 2*imag*real + imagC;
                real = temp;
                if (real*real + imag*imag >= 4) {
                    broken = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!broken) {
                g.fillRect(x, y, cellSize, cellSize);
            }
        }
    }
    count = count + 0.04;
    setTimeout(function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(drawFractal);
    }, 41);
}

drawFractal();
```

Answer (score -2):

You are using setInterval() to call drawFractal every 60 ms, and then every time drawFractal is executed, you're calling setInterval() *again*, which is unnecessary.  You now have two timers attempting to draw fractals every 60 ms... then you'll have 4, then 8, etc.

You need to either (1) call setInterval() once at the start of program execution and not call it again, or (2) switch to using setTimeout(), and call it at the end of each drawFractal().

I'd use the second option, just in case your fractal ever takes more than 60 ms to draw.

Comment: This is not what is occurring.